# Computation failed for stat_summary, 'what' must be a character string or a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to following the script/example on `ChickWeight` plotting raw data in "Independent Group T intervals test", but keeps running into the following error for `stat_summary` function

Code to reproduce here:

```
library(datasets) 
data(ChickWeight)

library(ggplot2) 
g <- ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight, 
                         colour = Diet, group = Chick))
g <- g + geom_line()

g <- g + stat_summary(aes(group = 1), geom = "line", fun.y = mean, size = 1, color = "black")

g <- g + facet_grid(. ~ Diet)
```

> Error message:
>   "Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
>   'what' must be a character string or a function"

The error message is not very intuitive, I do not even see "what" as a param in the documentation of `stat_summary`, I did some research and check for others' answers but so far no concrete answer or solution to this problem.

Comment: It works fine for me. But what do you mean by aes(group = 1) in your call to stat_summary?

Comment: If I copy/paste that into R, I don't get the same error you do. Did you try from a fresh R session?

Comment: Which version of `ggplot2` are you using? With version 2.2.1, your code works for me.

Comment: Related issue? https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1937

Answer (score 11):

The reason is that you have a variable called `mean` in your workspace. So when you call `stat_summary` …

```
stat_summary(aes(group = 1), geom = "line", fun.y = mean, size = 1, color = "black")
```

… R thinks that you’re referring to that variable, rather than the `mean` function from the {base} package.

R is *usually* able to disambiguate between functions and other variables, even if they have the same name. However, in this case the disambiguation isn’t working because you’re not calling `mean` directly but passing it as an argument. The solution is to manually disambiguate the *function* from the *variable* by doing either of these things:

1. In the call to `stat_summary`, use the fully qualified name `base::mean`, rather than bare `mean`.
2. In the call to `stat_summary`, use `match.fun(mean)` instead of bare `mean`: this will tell R that you want to use a *function*.
3. Remove or rename the variable.

Answer (score 4):

Similar problem for `geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)`, I got exactly the same error message. Because I have **lm** in my global environment.
Just fixed the problem by changing `lm` to `"lm"`:
`geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)`

Comment: konrad answer's is more precise but this trick works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to plot summary stats for categories for a given continuous variable. The problem for mine was:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
   geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
                 stat = "summary",
                 fun.ymax = max,
                 fun.ymin = min,
                 fun.y = median)
```

Functions are not called here as objects. After trying string form this worked for me:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
      geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
                 stat = "summary",
                 fun.ymax = "max",
                 fun.ymin = "min",
                 fun.y = "median")
```

Answer (score 0):

same problem here.

For me the trick was also that I needed strings as parameters. Example:

```
expBar + stat_summary(fun.y = "sum", geom = "bar", fill = "white", colour = "black")
```

instead of

```
expBar + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "bar", fill = "white", colour = "black")
```

made it work.

Hope that helps,

rikojir

Answer (score 0):

Some of my students experienced that error because there were superfluous variables in the dataframe (that had not been dropped before/during the use of the `reshape` function). Try creating a temporary dataframe where variables that will not be used are dropped.

```r
df_temp <- df[c("needed1", "needed2", "needed3")]
```

You may also drop variables using `-`before them.